# Unable to generate classes for swagger

Tags: swagger, codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am using the following config to generate swagger:

```
java: 6
swagger-codegen-maven-plugin: 2.1.3
io.swagger: 1.5.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core: 2.7.0
```

When i run maven install(from intellij), get this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.1.3:generate (default) on project <project>: Execution default of goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.1.3:generate failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.1.3:generate: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=io/swagger/parser/SwaggerParser, offset=6
```

Can someone please help with it?

Answer (score 1):

Swagger Codegen requires Java 8 or later.